# Extensible toolkits or approaches to sniffing file formats from messy data?

Tags: parsing, pattern-matching, file-format, sniffing

Are there any frameworks out there to support file format sniffing using declarative, fuzzy schema and/or syntax definitions for the valid formats? I'm looking for something that can handle dirty or poorly formatted files, potentially across multiple versions of file format definitions/schemas, and make it easy to write rules- or pattern-based sniffers that make a best guess at file types based on introspection.

I'm looking for something declarative, allowing you define formats descriptively, maybe a DSL, something like:

```
format A, v1.0:
  is tabular
  has a "id" and "name" column
  may have a "size" column
    with integer values in 1-10 range
 is tab-delimited
 usually ends in .txt or .tab

format A, v1.1:
  is tabular
  has a "id" column
  may have a "name" column
  may have a "size" column
    with integer values in 1-10 range
  is tab- or comma-separated 
  usually ends in .txt, .csv or .tab
```

The key is that the incoming files may be mis-formatted, either due to user error or poorly implemented export from other tools, and the classification may be non-deterministic. So this would need to support multiple, partial matching to format definitions, along with useful explanations. A simple voting scheme is probably enough to rank guesses (i.e. the more problems found, the lower the match score).

For example, given the above definitions, a comma-delimited "test.txt" file with an "id" column and "size" column with no values would result in a sniffer log something like:

```
Probably format A, v1.1
  - but "size" column is empty

Possibly format A, v1.0
  - but "size" column is empty
  - but missing "name" column
  - but is comma-delimited
```

The Sniffer functionality in the Python standard library is heading in the right direction, but I'm looking for something more general and extensible (and not limited to tabular data). Any suggestions on where to look for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am glad I have found this question - I am thinking of something similar too (declarative solution to markup any file format and feed it, along with the file itself, to the tool that can verify the file).

What you are naming "sniffer" is widely known as "file carver" and this person is big at carving: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simson_Garfinkel

Not only he has developed an outstanding carver, he has also provided the definition of different cases of incomplete files.

So, If you are working on some particular file format repair tool - check the aforementioned classification to find out how complex is the problem. For example, carving from incompletely received data stream and carving from disk image defers significantly. Carving from disk image with fragmented disk would be insanely more difficult, whereas padding some video file with meaningless data, just to make it open by video player is easy - you just have to provide the correct format.

Hope it helped.

Regards